# Make readxl::read_excel rename only the second duplicate column in R

Tags: r, readr, readxl

In readr, the `read_csv` command handles duplicate column names by renaming the second duplicate and leaves the first unaltered.  See the following example, taken from https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/53.

```
readr::read_csv("x,x,y\n1,2,3\n")
#> Warning: Duplicated column names deduplicated: 'x' => 'x_1' [2]
#> # A tibble: 1 × 3
#>       x   x_1     y
#>   <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     2     3
```

How can I get `readxl::read_excel` handle duplicate columns the same way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `.name_repair` argument and pass `make.unique()` as a function:

```
library(readxl)

read_excel(path = "temp.xlsx", .name_repair = ~make.unique(.x, sep = "_"))

# A tibble: 1 x 3
      x   x_1     y
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     3
```

Comment: This does what I asked, but it has a bad side effect.  My actual Excel files have blank columns (I have no control over this).  So it leaves the first blank column named as the empty string, which causes problems with dplyr down the road.  I can use `select(-"") `. to fix, but I'm just curious, is it possible to pre-empt this problem on the read-in?

Comment: You can rename the empty columns to something more identifiable on the read-in (so they become for example ("blank", "blank_1") etc - then you can easily remove them with using `select(-starts_with("blank"))`.   is that what you had in mind?

Comment: Sort of.  I think you're still describing a rename after the read in, which seems like it would totally work, but I'm still academically curious about whether it could be done as part of the read in function call itself.

Comment: Not exactly - the rename is part of the read-in using name repair.  `read_excel(path = "temp.xlsx", .name_repair = ~make.unique(sub("^$", "blank", .x), sep = "_")) %>%
  select(-starts_with("blank"))`